# Как удалить в списке словарей ключ вместе со значением, по имени ключа?

Tags: python, list, dict

Есть список, имеющий вид:

```
[ { 'id': 654321, 'owner_id': 123456, 'track_covers': [], 'url': 'https://**********=1', 'artist': 'Название исполнителя', 'title': 'Название трека', 'duration': 244 } , { 'id': 654321, 'owner_id': 123456, 'track_covers': [], 'url': 'https://**********=1', 'artist': 'Название исполнителя 2', 'title': 'Название трека 2', 'duration': 127 } , { 'id': 654321, 'owner_id': 123456, 'track_covers': [], 'url': 'https://**********=1', 'artist': 'Название исполнителя 3', 'title': 'Название трека 3', 'duration': 269 } ]
```

На сколько я понимаю, в нем содержатся словари в фигурных скобках {}, а у словарей есть ключи, такие как id или url.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в подобном списке удалить из содержащихся в нем словарей, определенные ключи вместе с их значениями? Т.е. что бы в итоге осталось:

```
[ { 'artist': 'Название исполнителя', 'title': 'Название трека' } , { 'artist': 'Название исполнителя 2', 'title': 'Название трека 2' } , { 'artist': 'Название исполнителя 3', 'title': 'Название трека 3']
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement

Answer (score 2):

```
new_dict_list = [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in ['artist','title']} for d in dict_list]

[{'artist': 'Название исполнителя', 'title': 'Название трека'},
 {'artist': 'Название исполнителя 2', 'title': 'Название трека 2'},
 {'artist': 'Название исполнителя 3', 'title': 'Название трека 3'}]
```

Можно, конечно, и в исходном удалить, но такие удаления часто ведут к неявным ошибкам, обычно лучше сделать новый список из новых объектов.

Comment: Но и делать множественные копии всего подряд тоже зачастую нет смысла, а код вида `del d['artist']` ещё и более читабельный

Comment: @andreymal Случаи разные бывают, конечно. Тут сами объекты ведь те же останутся, в новые словари переедут только ссылки на уже имеющиеся объекты-строки, никаких копий. И старый словарь можно удалить после этого.